# How to delete multiple environment variables in BluePrism?

Tags: blueprism

I am able to delete only single environment variable at a time in BluePrism version 6.6 How can we delete multiple of them at once? I am not able to select multiple environment variables at once.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way (but be careful) is to execute a delete statement on the SQL database with criteria set up to match whatever env variables you want deleted.

Example if you have a naming convention on your env vars like
ID_name_function

You could execute a statement of

```
Delete from tablename
Where name like '%ID%'
```

In this case the ID being the identifying variable of the environment variable. You can also write a multiple delete function either.

You will need to speak to whoever governs and monitors the Database to fulfill this action however unless there is a dire need to do this frequently you likely wont be allowed to do it.

Comment: I want to delete from the blueprism window, not by executing SQL commands. I can remove variable one by one from window but how to multiselect them and delete?

Comment: far as i'm aware you cannot do this

Comment: Ok, I think there should be a product fix for this. Nonetheless I made a new database connection in Blue Prism to work from scratch.

Comment: I am not sure why you needed a new connection to the database to work from scratch. That isn't related to env variables. And there is a product for it, it's the SQL script I mentioned above. Maybe Blueprism will write the function in the next release who knows.